# Inside door latch not working - Toyotta Corolla 2002

Tags: maintenance, toyota, door

I have an Toyotta Corolla 2002 and sometime ago is not anymore possible to open the passenger door by inside.

Opening the passenger door using the exterior handle is working only the inside handle/latch is not working.

I opened the door and there is a 'metal' rod that go from the inside plastic lath (passenger side) until 'someplace' and makes the door open.

On this car all the system is 'mechanical' I have check the later documentantion and the iron rod was substituted for plastic cables.

My question is:

1- Anyone have clear instructions how to fix that?
2- Any diagrams how to fix the iron rod in a way that does not fall.

PS. I opened all the door, tried to fix the metal rod and when I closed the door bang... it falls apart... (after 4 hours of work)

All the instructions on internet talk about if the latch is broken... My latch is ok... The problem is the metal rod that when the latch lever is pulled opens the door.

Thanks

Comment: Clarifying. The Inside Latch side is ok, the problem is :
Where I fit the other side of the rod?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a small clip to hold the end of the metal rod into the mechanism. They are usually made of either a bit of thin folded sheet metal, or moulded plastic, as shown in the circle at the bottom of this image (which appears to be for a Honda of some sort, but is the clearest Google came up with):

[image: Door Handle Clip]

Comment: Thanks for your Help, but this part is OK,
I am looking for instructions for the other side of the metal rod...
This 'side' is ok, but where I fit the other side of the iron rod?

Comment: I would expect to see a similar clip at the other end where the rod meets the lock mechanism

Comment: I expect too, tried to 'cling' it there, but it seems there is a smart way to do that...